# How to get autocomplete for turtle.Screen object?

Tags: python, pycharm

Trying to get started with Python, autocomplete would be very useful.

As I now understand, Python is dynamically typed and defining the return type of functions is not required. Not so great for autocomplete, obviously.

Therefore I tried to type-hint my local variable in order to enable the IDE to autocomplete. While the IDE checks the existence of the type I hint, this seems to have no effect on auto complete at all.

Is there a way to get autocomplete or should I forget about it when using Python?

This is my code:

```
import turtle


def draw_square():
    screen = turtle.Screen()    # type: turtle.Screen
    screen.bgcolor("blue")
    screen.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is autocomplete feature present in pycharm. I'm using pycharm professional. I have attached a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Indeed it works if you get the screen via the protected member, which shows a warning. If I use the `turtle.Screen()` method instead, I did not find a way to enable auto complete on the returned screen object, even when using the type hint comment.